# Python's semaphore hangs for ever

Tags: python, multithreading, semaphore

Im trying to do things concurrently in my program and to throttle the number of processes opened at the same time (10).

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from threading import BoundedSemaphore

semaphore = BoundedSemaphore(10)
for x in xrange(100000):
  semaphore.acquire(blocking=True)
  print 'new'
  p = Process(target=f, args=(x,))
  p.start()

def f(x):
  ...  # do some work
  semaphore.release()
  print 'done'
```

The first 10 processes are launched and they end correctly (I see 10 "new" and "done" on the console), and then nothing. I don't see another "new", the program just hangs there (and Ctrl-C doesn't work either). What's wrong ?

Comment: Why not just use `multiprocessing.Pool`?

Comment: What makes you think `threading.BoundedSemaphore`'s `release` will be seen across process boundaries?

Comment: @Thanatos semaphore is a global object and acquire is supposed to be blocking as said in the doc ; am I missing something ?

Comment: @g.d.d.c Noted, I tried it and Im pretty happy with it, but I am still interested to know why this doesn't work

Comment: possible duplicate of [BoundedSemaphore hangs in threads on KeyboardInterrupt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/936933/boundedsemaphore-hangs-in-threads-on-keyboardinterrupt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the use of `threading.BoundedSemaphore` across process boundaries:

```
import threading
import multiprocessing
import time

semaphore = threading.BoundedSemaphore(10)


def f(x):
  semaphore.release()
  print('done')


semaphore.acquire(blocking=True)
print('new')
print(semaphore._value)
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=f, args=(100,))
p.start()
time.sleep(3)
print(semaphore._value)
```

When you create a new process, the child gets a copy of the parent process's memory. Thus the child is decrementing it's semaphore, and the semaphore in the parent is untouched. (Typically, processes are isolated from each other: it takes some extra work to communicate across processes; this is what `multiprocessing` is for.)

This is opposed to threads, where the two threads share the memory space, and are considered the same process.

`multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore` is probably what you want. (If you replace `threading.BoundedSemaphore` with it, and replace `semaphore._value` with semaphore.get_value()`, you'll see the above's output change.)

Answer (score 0):

Your bounded semaphore is not shared properly between the various processes which are being spawned; you might want to switch to using [multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore](http://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936933/boundedsemaphore-hangs-in-threads-on-keyboardinterrupt) for some more details.

Comment: I saw this question which seemed different in the first place. Now with the answer I see that he used `threading.` instead of `multiprocessing.` too which is why he asked the question